# When in python on a Mac, how do you bring in 2 separate columns from a csv file and use them separately?

Tags: python, macos, csv, python-3.x, multiple-columns

I am trying to bring in 2 columns from a CSV file into my Python notebook and then be able to separate those to columns to different arrays or variables. How would this be done using xlrd and xlwt?

Comment: Why `xlrd`?  Wouldn't the `csv` module work?

Comment: I have actually saved it as an .xlsx file because I am having problems with saving it as a CSV. This in turn changes my question around but I'm still asking the same thing just in terms of a xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a numpy array using xlrd/xlwt or any other data to row-wise array module, and then transpose that data so you could simply pull the column as a single array.

```
import numpy
original = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
numpified = numpy.array(a)
transposed = numpified.transpose()

transposed[1] #this is the first column
transposed[2] #this is the second column
transposed[3] #this is the third column
```

There are lot's of alternative ways to do this, but I think this is one of the easier ones to use.

If you can't get the elements into an array or dictionary form then you will have to accomplish that first, at which point I recommend doing the conversion in such a way that you just have the data as you want it.

If you ever have to walk through data in a loop you can always add to a column as follows:

```
myDataset = [some array of comma seperated rows]
column1 = []
column2 = []

for myLine in myDataset
    myLine = myLine.split(",") #This assumes you are using comma seperated items
    #Change formatting to fit your actual dataset.
    column1.append(myLine[0])
    column2.append(myLine[1])
```

Above is just an example, but it helps in more generic cases where you need to seperate data into two or more distinct arrays or dictionaries.